# Not able to install any package or software on Linux 64-bit

Tags: linux, command-line

I am using Linux RHEL6 and not able to install any package.

```
[root@linux6 Python-2.7.9]# uname -a
Linux linux6.4 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 29 11:47:41 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@linux6 Python-2.7.9]# ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... 32-bit
checking MACHDEP... linux2
checking EXTRAPLATDIR... 
checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/usr/src/Python-2.7.9':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
[root@linux6 Python-2.7.9]#
```

Tried with linux32 but no luck:

```
[root@linux6 Python-2.7.9]# linux32 ./configure
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... 32-bit
checking MACHDEP... linux2
checking EXTRAPLATDIR... 
checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/usr/src/Python-2.7.9':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: You are trying to install from source, but you don't seem to have the C compiler installed. Have you tried to install the prerequisites for Python on RHEL using `yum`?

Comment: yes I have tried it. but no luck

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you don't have a C compiler.

Do this: `yum install gcc gcc-c++ autoconf automake`

[More info about installing a C compiler are here.](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-c-cpp-compiler-on-rhel)

Comment: I have tried it but getting the below error.

Comment: [root@linux6 ~]# yum install gcc gcc-c++ autoconf automake
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
There was an error communicating with RHN.
RHN Satellite or RHN Classic support will be disabled.

Error Message:
    Service not enabled for system profile: "linux6.4"
Error Class Code: 31

Comment: 1. [Troubleshoot](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/189533)
2. [How to register and subscribe a system to the Red Hat Customer Portal using Red Hat Subscription-Manager](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/253273)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and comments, it appears that your problem comes from not being subscribed to Red Hat Network, so you can't install yum packages.

You can subscribe [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/253273).  However, note that this is a paying subscription; if you're a Linux hobbist and trying to run an evaluation copy of Red Hat, you might want to install [CentOS](https://www.centos.org/) instead which is basically a free RHEL.